# Is the regulation of lactose operon different between Gram + and Gram -?

Tags: microbiology, gene-expression

I know that in E. coli the lactose operon is shut down by CAP protein when binding cAMP. Is this true also for Gram positive bacteria?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's stupid but I answer my own question, for those who are interested.
It is different.  CAP protein regulates lactose operon only in Gram -. In Gram + the presence of glucose shuts down the operon with another mechanism: the TCRS that relies to concentration of fructose 1,6 phosphate.

Comment: It is *not stupid* to answer your own question! It is actually encouraged on every SE site :)

Comment: Its not stupid at all. You saved our time